# Not saving custom taxonomy while using ajax

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, ajax

im doing a custom form to save a CPT with a custom taxonomy using ajax, everything saves fine but the custom taxonomy doesn't

I tried my code to save the CPT using only php and the taxonomy save without any problem

The select i use is

```
<select name="cat-servicios" class="cat-servicios">
   <option disabled value="">Seleciona una categoría</option>
   <?php foreach($terms_categorias as $term): ?>
       <option value="<?php echo esc_attr($term->slug); ?>"><?php echo esc_html($term->name); ?></option>
   <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

In my function to save the CT i use

```
    wp_set_post_terms($post_id,array($_POST['cat-servicios']),'categorias_servicios',true);
```

When i made a console.log of the value cat_services the input is correct but still doesn't save anything i also tried to use  `$('.cat-servicios :selected').val();` but i get the same error

```
$('#btn-click').on('click', function(){
        var cat_servicios = $('.cat-servicios').find(':selected').val();
        console.log(cat_servicios);
        var nombre_empresa = $('#nombre_empresa').val();
        var creacion_empresa = $('#creacion_empresa').val();
        var nit_empresa = $('#nit_empresa').val();
        var pagina_empresa = $('#pagina_empresa').val();
        var no_empleados = $('#no_empleados').val();
        var post_image = $('#post_image').val();
        var pd_empresa = $('#pd_empresa').val();
        var tempresa = $('#tempresa').val();
        var cl_empresa = $('.cl_empresa').val();
        var descripcion_empresa = $('#descripcion_empresa').val();
        var certificaciones_empresa = $('#certificaciones_empresa').val();
        var areas_empresa = $('#areas_empresa').val();
        var dep_empresa = $('.dep-empresas:selected').val();
        var mun_empresa = $('.mun-empresas:selected').val();
        var direccion_empresa = $('#direccion_empresa').val();
        var nombre_contacto = $('#nombre_contacto').val();
        var correo_elec1 = $('#correo_elec1').val();
        var correo_elec2 = $('#correo_elec2').val();
        var nro_tlf1 = $('#nro_tlf1').val();
        var nro_tlf2 = $('#nro_tlf2').val();

        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url : ajax_object.ajaxurl,
            data: {
                action:'themedomain_post_if_submitted',
                cat_servicios:cat_servicios,
                nombre_empresa:nombre_empresa,
                creacion_empresa:creacion_empresa,
                nit_empresa:nit_empresa,
                pagina_empresa:pagina_empresa,
                no_empleados:no_empleados,
                pd_empresa:pd_empresa,
                post_image:post_image,
                tempresa:tempresa,
                cl_empresa:cl_empresa,
                descripcion_empresa:descripcion_empresa,
                certificaciones_empresa:certificaciones_empresa,
                areas_empresa:areas_empresa,
                dep_empresa:dep_empresa,
                mun_empresa:mun_empresa,
                direccion_empresa:direccion_empresa,
                nombre_contacto:nombre_contacto,
                correo_elec1:correo_elec1,
                correo_elec2:correo_elec2,
                nro_tlf1:nro_tlf1,
                nro_tlf2:nro_tlf2,
            },   
            success: function(response){
                $(".success_msg").css("display","block");
                $("#new_post").hide();
            }, error: function(data){
                $(".error_msg").css("display","block");   
            }
        });
        
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have passed incorrect name($_POST key) in the function. Please use below code for saving the taxonomy:

```
wp_set_post_terms($post_id,array($_POST['cat_servicios']),'categorias_servicios',true);
```

You passed **cat-servicios** instead of **cat_servicios**

Thanks.